# camera.set_controls() not working on RasPI

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible that Camera.set_controls() doesn't work in pygame?
I am on Version 1.9.x and try it on my RasPi, but it always crashes.

It says there are no keyword arguments - But if I don't use keywords, it crashes with another message (I don't have the message in my mind at moment)

Errors:

[image]

This was sent via PuTTy, but it doesn't work if I directly use it on the RasPi, too.

Comment: is it possible to get and post the error messages?

Comment: It is, of course - Just not at the moment.

Comment: I edited the quetion: http://prntscr.com/ltqajb

Answer (score 0):

The error message is see unambiguously:

> ```
> set_controls() takes no keyword argument
> ```

So you can't write `camera.set_controls(hflip = True, vflip = True)`, but you have to write

```py
camera.set_controls(True, True)
```

Note `set_controls` is implmented using [CPython](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html). Also see [GitHub - Pygame - _camera.c](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/src_c/_camera.c)